# get row and column number Google spreadsheet - App script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to loop through the user selection and get the row and column indexes but it always returns the first-row index same for the column.

```
sheet.getActiveRangeList().getRanges().forEach((val, index, arr) => {
    val.getValues().forEach((e, index, arr) => {
      const row = val.getRow(); // always 2
      const columns = val.getColumn(); // always 1
    });
  });
```

does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

this returns the row values as an array but still, the row index is always 1

```
sheet.getSelection().getActiveRangeList().getRanges().forEach((value, index, arr) => {
    console.log(value.getRow()) // always 1
    console.log(value.getRowIndex()) // always 1
    console.log(value.getValues()) // row values as array
  })
```

**UPDATE 2**

When the user selects a range of rows and columns I would like to get range the selected rows and columns in that row.

Example:

```
[{selectedRow: selectedRow, selectedColumns[...columnIndex]}]
```

[Selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0am2.png) - [Selection 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrKWh.png) - [Selection 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fq4GT.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In the case of the following your image,

  [image]
- The array length retrieved by `sheet.getSelection().getActiveRangeList().getRanges()` is `1`. Because the selected area is 1. By this, `index` of `forEach((value, index, arr)` is only `0`. I think that this is the reason of your issue.
- If you want to retrieve the list of row and column numbers, it is required to retrieve them in the loop.

When above points are reflected to a script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var res = sheet.getActiveRangeList().getRanges().map(range => {
    const startRow = range.getRow();
    const endRow = startRow + range.getNumRows() - 1;
    const startColumn = range.getColumn();
    const endColumn = startColumn + range.getNumColumns() - 1;
    const temp = []
    for (var r = startRow; r <= endRow; r++) {
      for (var c = startColumn; c <= endColumn; c++) {
        temp.push({row: r, column: c});
      }
    }
    return {[range.getA1Notation()]: temp};
  });
  console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
}
```

#### Result:

When this script is run for your sample image, the following values are obtained.

```
[
  {"A1:C5": [
    {"row":1,"column":1},
    {"row":1,"column":2},
    {"row":1,"column":3},
    ,
    ,
    ,
  ]
}
```

#### References:

- [getActiveRangeList()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getactiverangelist)
- [getNumRows()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getnumrows)
- [getNumColumns()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getnumcolumns)

### Added:

When you want to retrieve the row and column indexes from the following situation,

[image]

how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var res = sheet.getActiveRangeList().getRanges().flatMap(range => {
    const startRow = range.getRow();
    const endRow = startRow + range.getNumRows() - 1;
    const startColumn = range.getColumn();
    const endColumn = startColumn + range.getNumColumns() - 1;
    const temp = []
    for (var c = startColumn; c <= endColumn; c++) {
      const tempObj = {selectedColumn: c, selectedRows: []};
      for (var r = startRow; r <= endRow; r++) {
        tempObj.selectedRows.push(r);
      }
      temp.push(tempObj);
    }
    return temp;
  });
  console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
}
```

#### Result:

When above script is run for the selected ranges of "A1:A5" and "C2:C5", the following result is obtained.

```
[
  {"selectedColumn":1,"selectedRows":[1,2,3,4,5]},
  {"selectedColumn":3,"selectedRows":[2,3,4,5]}
]
```

Comment: I might also have cases where the user might have blank column/rows between selection. Will I still be able to get only the selected cells by looping through the spreadsheet?

Comment: @t97 Thank you for replying. From your replying, I think that my proposed script works for multiple selected ranges. When you tested it, what result did you obtain?

Comment: @t97 By the way, from your question, I'm worry that I might not be able to correctly understand the output format you expect. If you want to retrieve the output values with the format you expect, can you provide the sample output values? By this, I would like to modify the sample script.

Comment: By selecting a single cell (C2) I got the following: `[{"C2":[{"row":2,"column":3},{"row":2,"column":4},{"row":3,"column":3},{"row":3,"column":4}]}]`.

Comment: @t97 Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I forgot about `-1` for `endRow` and `endColumn`. I updated it. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: thanks for doing that! I've added the output format in my original post. Do you think that's something that I can achieve by looping through the spreadsheet?

Comment: @t97 Thank you for replying. About your new question, if you want to retrieve the values from https://i.stack.imgur.com/fq4GT.png , I thought that it's not `[{selectedRow: selectedRow, selectedColumns[...columnIndex]}]` and it might be `[{selectedColumn: selectedColumn, selectedRows[...rowIndex]}]`. How about this?

Comment: @t97 Thank you for replying. For the sample image of https://i.stack.imgur.com/fq4GT.png , I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it?